# How to diagnose a problem using a core dump?

Tags: core-dump

I have the following core dump:

```
pth_signal.pthread_kill(??, ??) at 0xd0124734
pth_signal._p_raise(??) at 0xd01241a4
raise.raise(??) at 0xd038acd0
abort.abort() at 0xd03eeb78
_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE(handler = ??), line 47 in "eh_terminate.cc"
_ZSt9terminatev(), line 57 in "eh_terminate.cc"
__cxa_throw(obj = ??, tinfo = ??, dest = ??), line 77 in "eh_throw.cc"
unnamed block in _Znwm(sz = 4048060128), line 54 in "new_op.cc"
unnamed block in _Znwm(sz = 4048060128), line 54 in "new_op.cc"
unnamed block in _Znwm(sz = 4048060128), line 54 in "new_op.cc"
_Znwm(sz = 4048060128), line 54 in "new_op.cc"
_Znam(sz = ??), line 36 in "new_opv.cc"
_ZN7PROFILEC1ERK6STRING(this = @0x2fe74398, iniFilename = @0x21973300), line 99 in "profile.cpp"
_ZN2IE17AppendToBDataListEP10BASKETDATA(this = @0x2130eb38, bd = 0x2fe7f000), line 2451 in "ie.cpp"
_ZN5DIEGO14HandleResponseEP10BASKETDATAPv(this = 0x2130eb38, bd = 0x2fe7f000, args = 0x2fe71d78), line 513 in "diegoclass.cpp"
_ZThn68_N5DIEGO14HandleResponseEP10BASKETDATAPv(0x2130eb7c, 0x2fe7f000, 0x2fe71d78), line 21 in "diegoclass.h"
_ZN8KOBJBASE8dispatchEiP10BASKETDATAPv(this = 0x2130eb7c, fcnidx = 12, bd = 0x2fe7f000, args = 0x2fe71d78), line 67 in "kobjbase.cpp"
_ZN6KERNEL8DispatchEPcS0_iP10BASKETDATAPvR4LISTI8KOBJBASEE(this = @0x2fe71d38, module = "diego", method = "HandleResponse", fcn_idx = 12, bd = 0x2fe7f000, args = 0x2fe71d78, thread_objects = @0xf156dd58), line 1118 in "skernel.cpp"
unnamed block in _ZN6KERNEL9ExecuteTXEP10BASKETDATA(this = @0x2fe71d38, bd = 0x2fe7f000), line 224 in "txthread.cpp"
unnamed block in _ZN6KERNEL9ExecuteTXEP10BASKETDATA(this = @0x2fe71d38, bd = 0x2fe7f000), line 224 in "txthread.cpp"
_ZN6KERNEL9ExecuteTXEP10BASKETDATA(this = @0x2fe71d38, bd = 0x2fe7f000), line 224 in "txthread.cpp"
unnamed block in _ZN6KERNEL22ProcessEnqueuedBasketsEP6BASKET(this = @0x2fe71d38, b = @0x2fe7ef68), line 1162 in "skernel.cpp"
```

How can I use the core dump to fix the crash I'm having?

Answer (score 6):

First, you run that output through `c++filt`, which demangles the C++ symbols into human-readable, and source-code cross-reference-able output.

From that you see that the PROFILE constructor has called `new[]` which has caused an exception to be raised for which there is no handler (std::terminate is called), which causes the program to abort, generating a core dump.

You can wrap the call to `new[]` in a `try...catch` block to see what the exception is. I cannot remember off the top of my head what exceptions `new[]` can raise and under what circumstances, but one cause of `new` failures is a corrupt heap, commonly from either overwriting the bounds of an allocation or a double `delete`.

You can diagnose these memory errors using programs like `valgrind` (free) or `purify` (commercial, assuming it still exists - I last used it 15 years ago). `valgrind` would be a good start and it will show you your memory errors of the form mentioned above.

You can go deeper with the core dump using `gdb` to inspect the memory image of your program at the time it crashed, but no-one here can really help with that - you need to know the structure of your code and the expected memory layout to do much with this.

Comment: Hi camh, thanks for the quick response. I apriciate your suggestion. We will implement on our system.